# How to block third party cookies in Safari on Ventura?

Tags: safari

Chrome has an option to block third party cookies. Is it possible to do this on Safari. I am using Safari 16.5 on Ventura. In Settings I can see:

[image]

but clicking on block all cookies blocks all the cookies instead of just third party cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To block third-party cookies in Safari (16.5), you have to disable "Block all cookies" and enable "**Prevent cross-site tracking**".

This option blocks cross-site tracking (as by its name) but also third-party cookies as explained in [Prevent cross-site tracking in Safari on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/safari/sfri40732/mac):

> Unless you visit and interact with the third-party content provider as a first-party website, their [cookies and website data](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/safari/aside/glos0126d795/16.1/mac/13.0) are deleted.